# What is an equation that designs a rollercoaster, that will go into desmos.

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions, desmos

The rollercoaster has to fit the following criteria:

- Starts and finishes at ground level (does not go underground)
- Maximum height is 100m and maximum horizontal displacement is 1000m
- The cross-section profile must include 2-3 different functions (preferably beginning with a cubic, then parabola, then straight line).
- At least one linear equation and a polynomial of degree 2-3.

then label the parts that are differentiable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Example design:

You are asking for piecewise curves pasted together. If you are going to use $f_i(x)$ and $f_{i+1}(x)$ adjacently and paste them at $x=x^*$ then choose $x^*$ such that $f_i(x^*) = f_{i+1}(x^*)$ (naturally for pasting) and $\frac{\partial^k f_i(x^*)}{\partial^k x} = \frac{\partial^k f_{i+1}(x^*)}{\partial^k x}$ for $k = [1,K]$ with $K$ as large as possible without making $f_i= f_{i+1}$. for example if you are pasting linear and quadratic together i.e., $f_i(x) = ax$ and $f_{i+1}(x) = bx^2$ then $K = 1$ inother words $K = \max(\deg(f_i),\deg(f_{i+1})) - 1$. If these equalities are satisfied, just come up with $f_i's$ which fit your area and keep pasting them.

This is a theoretical roller coaster where criteria is to make the transition between curves as smooth as possible. Include your practical constraints and design them with safety measures.

Comment: Hi this is confusing to me. Could you please put it into one equation where i can simply sub it into desmos and the rollercoaster will be there.

Comment: We are placing several curves adjacently. FOr example for $0\leq x \leq 1$, we use curve $f_1(x)$ and for $1 \leq x \leq 2$, we use curve $f_2(x)$,....for $i -1 \leq x \leq i$, we use the curve $f_i(x)$. Now i have explained in my answer the relation between $f_i(x)$ and $f_{i+1}(x)$ at $x^* = i$ where both the curves coincide and roller coaster must smoothly move. the curves are the trajectories of roller coaster and $x$ is the location co-ordinates of a particular point in roller coaster and $f(x)$ is the height of the roller coaster at the co-ordinates $x$..

Comment: You can generalize the idea to 3 dimensions. What i explained is a 2-D roller coaster in my previous comment and answer.